# Android Studio 3.6 : Unable to run apk on emulator or device

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-emulator, android-install-apk, android-studio-3.6

After Updating Android Studio to the version 3.6, I am unable to install an app directly to device by using Run button.

It just updates the gradle and shows gradle updated popup that's it.

I tried invalidating cache and recreating the emulator device but no luck yet.

Let me know if anyone could help as am **creating APK and installing it manually in emulator.**

Comment: Are you generating signed apk or debug apk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have installed the Android Studio 3.6 and suddenly existing project stopped running. I tried the following thing and it worked.

Android Studio -> Run -> Edit Configurations -> Installation options -> Select Nothing instead of Default apk.

[image]

Comment: gets stuck at launching activity.

Answer (score 3):

I am not able to post this as comment, but maybe someone finds this info useful.
I faced same problem after updating Android Studio to 3.6.1 on Mac OS.
I tried to use gradle task for installing and launching my application and I found strange log in console about missing adb in platform-tools folder.

So, as result: after update folder `platform-tools` was moved into folder with same name (was: `sdk/platform-tools` become: `sdk/platform-tools/platform-tools`). I just move it manually back and everything is worked as a charm.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It might be worth leaving it there and updating Android Studio to point to the new location, otherwise you could be moving it every time you update

Answer (score 0):

I have installed **Android Studio 3.6** yesterday. I have tried both way to install APK.

1. Directly by Run button. [DEVICE - Working, Emulator - Working]
2. Generated APK, Drag and Drop to Emulator. (Its also working)

Hope It will work for you too. Just drag n drop APK file to emulator.

> **Bonus** - May your emulator is older, You can update your Emulator from
>   SDK Manager and Create New.

Comment: it's a debug apk.  and 2nd option is working but it's taking lot of time so need to resolve the 1st option.

Comment: What is the size of your APK? and If it's taking too much time then may your PC/Laptop configuration also affect.

Comment: It's 27 MB and config is also good. gradle build finishes in 5 to 10 sec without any error so no trace to dig